# Associate a color palette with ggplot2 theme

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my ggplot2 theme to use a specific set of colors, but don't see how to avoid a separate line outside of the theme.

I have this data:

```
library(ggplot2)
mycars <- mtcars
mycars$cyl <- as.factor(mycars$cyl)
```

And here's a dummy theme I plot with:

```
mytheme <- theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 2))

ggplot(mycars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = cyl)) +
  mytheme
```

[image: without custom colors]

I want the point colors to default to my custom palette:

```
mycolors <- c("deeppink", "chartreuse", "midnightblue")
```

Can I somehow add that to my ggplot2 theme so that I don't constantly repeat this extra line of code at the end:

```
ggplot(mycars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = cyl)) +
  mytheme +
  scale_color_manual(values = mycolors)
```

[image: with colors]

I tried:

```
mytheme2 <- mytheme + scale_color_manual(values = mycolors)
```

But got:

> Error: Don't know how to add scale_color_manual(values = mycolors) to
>   a theme object

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hi you can put your custom element in a `list` :

```
# Data
library("ggplot2")
mycars <- mtcars
mycars$cyl <- as.factor(mycars$cyl)

# Custom theme
mytheme <- theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 2))
mycolors <- c("deeppink", "chartreuse", "midnightblue")
# put the elements in a list
mytheme2 <- list(mytheme, scale_color_manual(values = mycolors))

# plot 
ggplot(mycars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = cyl)) +
  mytheme2
```

Comment: It looks like this won't cause problems when I'm using this theme on charts where `scale_color_manual` is not applicable.  I'm playing with adding on to it for other color scenarios and it seems to work fine, e.g., `mytheme2 <- list(mytheme, scale_color_manual(values = mycolors), scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors))` to cover both fill and color aesthetics.

Answer (score 10):

I sometimes use this little trick to change colour palettes between plots,

```
library(ggplot2)
mycars <- mtcars
mycars$cyl <- as.factor(mycars$cyl)

scale_colour_discrete <- function(...) scale_colour_manual(values=palette())

(p <- ggplot(mycars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = cyl)) )
```

[image]

```
palette(c("deeppink", "chartreuse", "midnightblue"))
p
```

[image]

```
palette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, "Set1"))
p
```

[image]

Comment: Small modification to allow for more options: pass the "..." to scale_colour_manual, that is:
scale_colour_discrete <- function(...) scale_colour_manual(..., values=palette())