# Incorporate single color to ggplot2 theme

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I want to make a theme for ggplot2 that defines a certain color palette to be used when one or more colors are used. I know how to do it when a plot uses multiple colors (described over here: [Associate a color palette with ggplot2 theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476751/associate-a-color-palette-with-ggplot2-theme)). However, I also want to be able to use a preset color for when plots only use a single color.

#### Example

Let's assume I have these data:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x + rnorm(100, sd=.4)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
```

And the following theme:

```
t <- theme_bw()
myColors <- c('red', 'blue', 'black')
s <- scale_color_manual(values = myColors)
myTheme <- list(t, s)
```

Now I plot the data:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + myTheme
```

And I get the following plot:

[plot without color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPmzy.png)

However, I would like the plot to use the first element in the `myColors` object. So I want to get the following plot (without having to explicitly define it `geom_point()`):

[plot with color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4byV.png)

#### Question

Is it possible to define a custom "main" color by using a theme in ggplot2?

Comment: Probably not without overloading `geom_point` or `GeomPoint`, as that color is not defined in either the scales or theme.

Comment: Conceptionally you request doesn't make sense. Color scales are not defined by the theme.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works in your actual situation, but you can introduce a dummy variable to set the colour as follows:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(aes(col=factor(1))) + myTheme
```

To suppress the legend, add `+ guides(colour=F)`

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for a way to set a "theme" that also includes a color scale and a default color used for the geoms. This way users can just add the theme, and everything in their plot (including the colors) will change without them having to add anything to their code. I looked into this some more and I think the only way of doing this is by overriding the defaults in the `geom` objects, something I'd rather not do.