# Integrate default color into personalized theme ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, ggthemes

I created my own theme and now I also want to standardize the color set that is used. I tried to do this with the list solution, provided in the answer of Viktor in this feed:

[Associate a color palette with ggplot2 theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476751/associate-a-color-palette-with-ggplot2-theme)

```
df <- mtcars
uwvPalet <- c("#0078D2","#003282","#C4D600")
theme_uwv <- function(base_size = 22, base_family = "Verdana"){theme_hc(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family)%+replace%theme(plot.title = element_text(color = rgb(0, 120, 210)), complete = TRUE)}
theme_uwv2 <- list(theme_uwv, scale_color_manual(values = uwvPalet))
ggplot(df, aes(fill = cyl, x = am, y = mpg)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity") + theme_uwv2()
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
Error in theme_uwv2() : could not find function "theme_uwv2"
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: You are calling `theme_uwv2` as a *function*, i.e. as `... + theme_uwv2**()**`. Do not, simply add the object, i.e. `... + theme_uwv2`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I get returned the error Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot

Comment: You also have to realise your `theme_uwv` in the list, i.e. in line 4, use `list(theme_uwv(), scale_color_manual...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me. `theme_uwv2` needed the value returned from `theme_uwv()` as a list element, not the function itself. Also, you were making a plot where the `fill` was the dominant colour variable, so I've substituted `scale_color_manual()` with `scale_fill_manual()` for demonstration purposes.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

df <- mtcars
uwvPalet <- c("#0078D2","#003282","#C4D600")
theme_uwv <- function(base_size = 22, base_family = "Verdana"){
  theme_hc(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(color = rgb(0, 120, 210, maxColorValue = 255)), 
          complete = TRUE)}
theme_uwv2 <- list(theme_uwv(), scale_fill_manual(values = uwvPalet))

ggplot(df, aes(fill = as.factor(cyl), x = am, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  ggtitle("test") +
  theme_uwv2
```

[image]